# setPixel() returns a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-image

Friends , when i tried to use the setPixel(x, y, color) in my app , it returns a NullPointerException and stopps working. Here is my code. Please help me to get out of the error. Thanks in advance

```
decode=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    decode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
            Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);



            int x=result.getPixel(10, 10);  
            int pixelAlpha=   Color.alpha(x);
            int red =   65;// represent character A
            int green=    Color.green(x);
            int blue=    Color.blue(x);

            int newPixel=Color.argb(pixelAlpha,red,green,blue);

            result.setPixel(10, 10, newPixel);   


             ImageView myNewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
             myNewImage.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception : "+exc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this will not fix your problem but use `int red = 'A';` rather than 65.

Comment: post your logcat. Before that: remove your try-catch so you have a "clean" exception.

Comment: Bro , if i remove the try and catch , the app will stop working without any notification,,, Soo i use try and catch here

Comment: If you remove the try catch block and it crashes without notification then you can pull open your logcat and grab the stack trace and share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);` could not properly decode your filePath.  Ensure result is not null and your filePath is correct.

Comment: Sorry , am new to android.. And how can i ensure my result is not null ? I tried to print it in an ImageView() , it works perfectly.. Is there any other way to decode the filePath

Comment: result is not null boss.